# Display votes for individual posts on the user popup window

Tags: feature-request, meta, meta-reputation

Getting upvotes on the main page adds an entry to list that is displayed when you hover over your user name

[image]

Can we have that on meta too? I'd like to know what people vote on, but it's difficult when the post is not a recent one...

Comment: And while we're at it, I call to restore the old meta reputation page. I was happy when I was able to track the votes on my answers, especially during periods when I was very active and would post several answers every week.

Comment: @AsafKaragila +1 definitely...